# Was a new monument or building discovered in Petra with Google Earth and drones?

Tags: archeology, google

Numerous different reports from June 2016 state that a new building was found in Petra with Google Earth. I can't find any external verification of these reports. Has this building been excavated? Is there any evidence that it exists other than satellite images? Has anyone proved that it wasn't a false-positive?

[Massive discovery ‘was hidden in plain sight in lost city’](http://www.news.com.au/travel/world-travel/middle-east/massive-discovery-was-hidden-in-plain-sight-in-lost-city/news-story/7ef7f631edd4ccc2b3ba291cba573073)

> IT WAS hidden in plain sight for thousands of years at a popular tourist spot. Now, this ancient monument has been uncovered using Google Earth and drones.

Mentions include,

- [Drones Lead Archaeologists To New Discovery In Petra, Jordan](http://www.npr.org/2016/06/10/481590386/drones-lead-archaeologists-to-new-discovery-in-petra-jordan)
- [Massive New Monument Found in Petra](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/2016/06/space-archaeology-satellite-petra-ancient-city-discovery-jordan-monument/)
- [Archaeologist finds hidden monument in ancient Jordan city](http://nypost.com/2016/06/11/archaeologist-finds-hidden-monument-in-ancient-jordan-city/)

The last of which says *"Tuttle said there are no plans to lay bare the entire platform."*

Answer (score 6):

The discovery is detailed in [Hiding in Plain Sight: The Discovery of a
New Monumental Structure at Petra,
Jordan, Using WorldView-1 and
WorldView-2 Satellite Imagery](http://asorblog.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/BASOR-Petra-Hiding-in-Plain-Sight.pdf) *Bulletin of the American Schools of Oriental Research* No. 375 (May 2016), pp. 35-51 (alternative [official link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.5615/bullamerschoorie.375.0035?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents))

"Building" is not the best word, but yes, ruins of buildings have been discover.

> A long north–south alignment of walls and
>   collapsed chambers from a building complex was identified
>   (Fig. 5, labeled CAT 2); no obvious function could be
>   determined from this preliminary visit, and the pottery
>   scatters included materials from the first century b.c.e.
>   through to at least the third century c.e. A more distinct
>   structure was also identified nearby (CAT 1). This was
>   an approximately 14 × 14 m elegant building built on a
>   small platform with its entrance on the east side; it contained
>   columns (Fig. 6), pilasters, a flagstone floor, and an external cistern with its cover stone in situ.

...

> There is one prominent structure on the interior platform
>   that is centered north–south but offset to the western
>   side. It measures 8.5 × 8.5 m, and its entrance was
>   centered on its east wall, the doorstep of which is still in
>   situ (Fig. 12). Only a partial single course of wall stones
>   is preserved above the foundation, and the state of the internal
>   floor could not be determined without excavation.
>   The structure’s walls were composed of only a single row of stones, generally laid using a header-stretcher configuration,
>   which suggests that the building was no more
>   than one or two stories in height. The small building may
>   have included at least one column at some point, as a
>   remnant of a single drum was visible buried outside the
>   west side (Fig. 13); this drum is smaller than those found
>   in situ on the east side of the smaller platform.

Yes, on the ground photographs are in the article, not just satellite photos.